# Rails - Factorygirl - Skip after_create Calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a factory for a model that I'd like to skip the after_create call backs when I create it. I've tried a few variations of the following (from another stackoverflow question), ...

```
before_create { |page| Page.skip_callback(:create, :after_create, :retrieve_stream_profile, :update_stream_profile) }
```

Basically, I'd like the model to be saved in the database when in an rspec test I do something like ...

```
  @page = FactoryGirl.create :page
```

but, I don't want any of the after_create callbacks to happen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to have multiple lines for each callback you'd like to skip. In my case, it'd look something like ...

```
after_build { |page| page.class.skip_callback(:create, :after, :add_page_for_superadmins) }
after_build { |page| page.class.skip_callback(:create, :after, :update_stream_profile) }
after_build { |page| page.class.skip_callback(:create, :after, :grab_stream) }
after_build { |page| page.class.skip_callback(:create, :after, :retrieve_past_insights) }
```

So, after building this page, skip all the callbacks. There may be a more elegant way to do this ... thinking about it, I don't think I tried an array as the last parameter for each of the four methods to skip.